# why Object reference not set to an instance of an object.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hi why this error is happened on **?

error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public static long GetID(string str1, string str2)
{
    using(MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        long Idold = db.old.FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldfield == str1).id; //**
        return db.tbl_new.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id_old == Idold && p.newfield == str2).id;           
    }
}
```

of course my tbl isn't empty .i set values to str1 and str2 that are exist in my tbl.

Comment: Probably this returns null: `FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldfield == str1)`, so that when you call `.id` on null, it throws.

Comment: Case sensitive strings? You should make sure that the string in your table (`oldfield`) has the same case as the string you compare it to (`str1`). `p.oldfield == str1`

Answer (score 2):

The method `db.old.FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldfield == str1)` will return `null` if it doesn't find a matching item. You're immediately trying to access the `id` property. You need to handle when no item is found.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious, there is no record in your database that matches the predicate. `FirstOrDefault()` method returns null and when you try to get `id` property it throws a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

The `OrDefault` portion of `FirstOrDefault` returns null when the predicate resolves to `false`.

If it is truly an exceptional case that there will be no items in your sequence, then use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, because `First` will throw an exception if there are no items.

However, if you expect the sequence to be empty some of the time, then you are better off using the `FirstOrDefault` logic and then checking for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldFriend == str1)` returned null. In other words, because there was no record with oldFriend equal to the str1 input.

Try this instead:

```
var oldFriend = db.old.FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldfield == str1);
if(oldFriend != null)
{
    long Idold = oldFriend.id;
    return db.tbl_new.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id_old == Idold && p.newfield == str2).id;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a stack trace I would guess its either the first or second line in your queries.

```
db.old.FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldfield == str1).Id

db.tbl_new.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id_old == Idold && p.newfield == str2).id
```

The FirstOrDefault returned null because it couldn't find an Id that equals your str2 or str1 variables

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all of you .
my good friends you were right . i used Trim() and worked.

```
     long Idold = db.old.FirstOrDefault(p => p.oldfield.Trim() == str1.Trim()).id;
```